# How to assign Stream method to a Function in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

I have a case as below:

```
RowDataSet rdsHavingMaxNumericValue = dataList.stream()
                    .filter(r -> r.getLong(NUMERIC_VALUE) != null)
                    .max((r1, r2) -> r1.getId().compareTo(r2.getId()))
                    .get();
```

I've two cases where I need to find either min or max depending on a case? how can i replace the call max at third line by a Function so that it direcly uses .apply() method and performs the operation?

I'v successfully assigned Collection.max or Collection min as below:

```
 BiFunction<List<RowDataSet>, Comparator<RowDataSet>, RowDataSet> mrOrlrOperation = expComponents[0] == 'M' ? Collections::max : Collections::min;
```

and i use it as below:

```
RowDataSet rds = mrOrlrOperation.apply(dataList, <some comparator>);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be simpler to just use a condition:

```
Stream<?> stream = dataList.stream()
                           .filter(r -> r.getLong(NUMERIC_VALUE) != null);
Comparator<RowDataSet> c = Comparator.comparingLong(RowDataSet::getId);
RowDataSet rdsHavingMaxNumericValue =
               expComponents[0] == 'M' ? stream.max(c).get() : stream.min(c).get();
```

You can store the min/max operation in a separate `Function` if you want:

```
BiFunction<Stream<RowDataSet>, Comparator<RowDataSet>, RowDataSet>> operation = 
             expComponents[0] == 'M' ? (s, c) -> s.max(c).get() : (s, c) -> s.min(c).get();

RowDataSet rdsHavingMaxNumericValue = operation.apply(stream, c);
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like the option, but i want to avoid the case lookup at runtime

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i do not want to perform any if else operations. i've left it as a last option

Comment: @Ajeetkumar I'm not sure I understand: how can you check the value of `expComponents` without a condition?

Comment: check my second example of Collections::max or ::min. So that function whenever runs it will directly use .apply, it won't check for min or max because it is already told to it that min or max is to be run. getting the idea?

Comment: @Ajeetkumar I'm not sure I understand *why* you want that but I've updated the answer to give an example.

Comment: I did that actually but anyways your answer matched my code. i want to do it because i want to avoid any if-else or decision making code at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

The choice to use `min` instead of `max` is not different to still using the `max` operation, but with a reversed order, so you could use

Initialization:

```
Comparator<RowDataSet> c = Comparator.comparingLong(RowDataSet::getId);
if(expComponents[0] != 'M') c = c.reversed();
```

Actual operation

```
RowDataSet rdsHavingMaxNumericValue =
    dataList.stream()
            .filter(r -> r.getLong(NUMERIC_VALUE) != null)
            .max(c)
            .get();
```

Reversing the order has no performance impact. It just implies calling `r2.getId().compareTo(r1.getId())` instead of `r1.getId().compareTo(r2.getId())`…

An alternative would be

```
Comparator<RowDataSet> c = Comparator.comparingLong(RowDataSet::getId);
BinaryOperator<RowDataSet> op = expComponents[0] == 'M'?
                                BinaryOperator.maxBy(c): BinaryOperator.minBy(c);

RowDataSet rdsHavingMaxNumericValue =
    dataList.stream()
            .filter(r -> r.getLong(NUMERIC_VALUE) != null)
            .reduce(op)
            .get();
```

This anticipates [what `min` and `max` would do](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java?av=f#513)…

---

You can use either variant to create your `BiFunction`, e.g.

Variant 1:

```
Function<Comparator<RowDataSet>, Comparator<RowDataSet>>
    maxOrMin = expComponents[0] == 'M'? Function.identity(): Comparator::reversed;

BiFunction<List<RowDataSet>, Comparator<RowDataSet>, RowDataSet> mrOrlrOperation
    = (dataList, comparator) -> dataList.stream()
                                        .filter(r -> r.getLong(NUMERIC_VALUE) != null)
                                        .max(maxOrMin.apply(comparator))
                                        .get();
```

Variant 2:

```
Function<Comparator<RowDataSet>, BinaryOperator<RowDataSet>>
    maxOrMin = expComponents[0] == 'M'? BinaryOperator::maxBy: BinaryOperator::minBy;

BiFunction<List<RowDataSet>, Comparator<RowDataSet>, RowDataSet> mrOrlrOperation
    = (dataList, comparator) -> dataList.stream()
                                        .filter(r -> r.getLong(NUMERIC_VALUE) != null)
                                        .reduce(maxOrMin.apply(comparator))
                                        .get();
```

Of course, you could also live with a code duplication

```
BiFunction<List<RowDataSet>, Comparator<RowDataSet>, RowDataSet> mrOrlrOperation
    = expComponents[0] == 'M'?
        (dataList, comparator) -> dataList.stream()
                                          .filter(r -> r.getLong(NUMERIC_VALUE) != null)
                                          .max(comparator)
                                          .get():
        (dataList, comparator) -> dataList.stream()
                                          .filter(r -> r.getLong(NUMERIC_VALUE) != null)
                                          .min(comparator)
                                          .get();
```

In either case, the condition `expComponents[0] == 'M'` is checked only once when the `BiFunction` is created and never evaluated when `mrOrlrOperation.apply(…)` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

`max` is a reducing operation, then you can use the generic `reduce`:

```
public void reducing(BiOperator<...> myFunction) {
    RowDataSet rdsHavingMaxNumericValue = dataList.stream()
                .filter(r -> r.getLong(NUMERIC_VALUE) != null)
                .reduce((r1, r2) -> myFunction.apply(r1,r2))
                .get();
}
...
reducing(Integer::max);
...
```

Comment: Hi, i find your answer interesting but have difficulty understanding it fully. BiFunction parameters are Integer, Integer, Integer ? in case of Integer::max, have you missed myFunction.apply call?